# Explicar para um iniciante a query "if (! achou)" no código

Tags: java, lógica, condição

Tenho um exercício que pesquisa um número em um vetor pré-determinado; e responde "foi encontrado e qual posição do vetor" ou responde que "o número não está no vetor". Queria a explicação de porque usar o `boolean achou = false` e da *query* `if (!achou)`. Eu sei que o programa tem que exibir 2 resultados se achou ou não achou o número, mas não entendi direito o que o uso do `boolean` e da negação dele no `if` estão fazendo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int vetor[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9};  // Cria o vetor com valores pré-definidos
    int numero;
    boolean achou = false;  // Variável para armazenar o resultado da procura

    System.out.println ("Qual número deseja procurar? ");       
    numero = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Qual número deseja procurar?"));
    
    
    
    for (int posicao = 0; posicao < 5; posicao++)
    {
        if (vetor[posicao] == numero)
        {
            System.out.println ("Encontrado na posição: "+ posicao+ "\n");
            achou = true;  
        }
    }
    
    if (! achou) 
    {
        System.out.println ("O número não está no vetor\n");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `!achou` é a mesma coisa de `achou == false`, só é um jeito mais chique de escrever

Comment: Esse `achou` existe porque no caso de não ter achado só dá pra saber após ter percorrido todo o vetor. Concordo que é desnecessário, um `break` eliminaria isso e resolveria uma ineficiência (se já achou pra que continuar percorrendo?). Na verdade (sendo um pouco chato porque volta e meia cometo esse pecado) o design não está bom, deveria haver uma função que só percorre e retorna se achou ou não, e outra que usa isso para dar essa informação ao usuário. O `!` é o operador de negação lógica que vem da álgebra de Boole (conceito ótimo para um iniciante em programação estudar).

Comment: Falei `break`? Quis dizer `return true`. :P A lógica deu uma falhada agora rs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, isso não é uma *query*.

Segundo, esse código é ineficiente, se achou ele deveria parar de procurar, e feito de forma eficiente e organizada, portanto a busca feita em uma função separada, essa variável nem seria necessária.

Esse tipo de variável chama-se *flag*, ou seja, ela só existe como uma bandeira para indicar um estado, e quase sempre tem um jeito melhor de fazer.

Então o código apenas controla se conseguiu achar o que estava procurando ou não. Ele começa considerando que não achou, então `achou` é falso. Quando ele achar (entrou no `if`) então muda o estado da variável (o ideal seria parar a busca ali mesmo), e mudando o estado a variável indica que ele achou o que estava procurando.

No fim ele verifica se achou ou não e decide se deve apresentar a mensagem dizendo que não achou. Obviamente ele só deve entra nesse `if` se o `achou` é falso, mas para entrar em um `if` o resultado deve ser verdadeiro, então como fazer um falso virar verdadeiro? Aplicando o operador booleano de NÃO (NOT), que é a exclamação, ou seja esse operador inverte o valor da variável booleana. Se não achou então ele entra ali.